# nodejs mongoose - how to check items in the database before login

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my project, I've different roles (seller/user/admin)and i want to check the role and redirect to specific page if they are seller for example.

I struggle on how i can check the role in Mongo DB before the login. My login page is basic email-password and submit button.

for my signup all is good, it's use the correct model and post it in the DB.

here are some pieces of my code:

(client model)

```
userSchema.statics.login = async function (email, password, role) {
  const user = await this.findOne({ email });

  if (user) {
    const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (auth) {
      return user;
    }
    throw Error("incorrect password");
  }

  throw Error("incorrect email");
};

const ClientModel = mongoose.model("client", userSchema, "users");
```

login controller:

```
module.exports.clientSignIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  
  try {
    const user = await LoginModel.login(email, password);
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge });
    res.redirect('/success');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
};
```

thanks in advance for your help, if you need more info please feel free to ask

Comment: where is your user role recorded? in `user` record or somewhere else??

Comment: @Salitha - All my users ar in the same collection "user"

Comment: You need to get the user information to check its role.
How is your user object? 
What does   const user = await this.findOne({ email }); returns?

If you don't have that information on user, you have to authenticate them, check their role and then redirect them.

On the clientSignIn method you have the user information (where you create the token using the user._id)
Before doing the res.redirect("/success"), you could try checking the user role.

Comment: @EAzevedo good point it's work i will put the solution but i really want to thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @EAzevedo 's advice.

i just change my Controller

```
module.exports.clientSignIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await LoginModel.login(email, password);
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge });
    if (user.role == "client") {
      res.redirect("/success");
    } else if (user.role == "technicien") {
      res.redirect("/success-technicien");
    } else if (user.role == "superuser") {
      res.redirect("/success-admin");
    };
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = signInErrors(err);
    res.status(200).json({ errors });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

when you get the user , you should have field for the role ,
then check which role logged in and redirect him to where he needs to be

Comment: Hi Micahel thanks for your answer, do i need to write it in my Model or in login controller ? thanks in advance

Comment: i dont know all your project structure but i think for now you might want to check it in login controller

Comment: ok but i don't know how to verify in database for the specific user, like req.body.role = ?

Comment: it is basic stuff , you will find a lot of guides in youtube/google .
```const user = await this.findOne({ email });``` this code is using the user Model in a strange way. 
you better search for a more standard way to do it.